# Access webserver from a USB-tethered Android

Tags: android, web-applications, raspberry-pi, bonjour, tethering

I made a small web app using flask on a raspberry pi, and I would like to access it from my phone, in a place without network (local or internet) connection. Using USB tethering, I can access my web app **if** I know its IP address. The server does not have a screen though, so it's a pain to figure out which IP address it received from Android.

Currently, I use Network Analyzer Pro to scan the full 192.168.x.x range, but it's very inconvenient and slow.

I figured that I could use Bonjour/Avahi/Zeroconf, and it works when connected to my local network, but not with a direct USB tethering connection.

Is there a way to make Android either 1) give me the IP address it gave to my webserver when it connected through USB, or 2) resolve the Bonjour address, 3) or any other solution to access my web app conveniently?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: AFAIK a static tethering address for clients can only be configured on rooted Android devices. You can avoid that by simply configuring the Raspberry to open a WiFi hotspot you can connect your Android phone to. The raspberry IP would then be fixed as WiFi owner.

Comment: @Robert, how does one open a wifi hotspot on a raspi? It has wifi yes. But can it be used as hotspot?

Comment: There was also a Fing Android app that showed connected devices.

Comment: Use the latest Raspberry OS version that based on Debian bookwork and uses network manager. Opening up a WiFi hotspot using network manager requires just about four command-line commands. This answer looks like the commands I have in mind https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/310699

Comment: Thank you Robert, that's a very appropriate and efficient solution! Creating a hotspot with Network Manager is extremely easy, and can even be done with the user interface (see [link](https://www.tomshardware.com/how-to/raspberry-pi-access-point)). This completely solve my issue. If you want to publish it as a solution, I will validate it, otherwise I'll create the answer myself. Thank you again!